# Stata: current date time like “yyyy-mm-dd.smcl” in log file name

Tags: stata

I would like to use do file for making log file name using Stata program.

Log file name: log_2015-11-26.smcl

If today is Nov. 26, 2015, is it possible?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the absence of code in questions often attracts flak, and understandably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stata will show you the current daily date if you display the global macro `S_DATE`. So you can retrieve that, convert it to a numeric daily date and push it out again in your desired format.

```
. di "$S_DATE"
26 Nov 2015

. local date = daily("$S_DATE", "DMY")

. di "`date'"
20418

. di %tdCY-N-D 20418
2015-11-26

. local date : di  %tdCY-N-D  daily("$S_DATE", "DMY")

. di "`date'"
2015-11-26

. log using log_`date'
```

Know that it worked. Minimalists could put the whole thing on one line

```
. log using log_`: di  %tdCY-N-D  daily("$S_DATE", "DMY")'
```

This all follows from `help macro` and `help dates` once you know about `S_DATE`.